# Shell script for using dos2unix on directories and sub directories for KornShell

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, dos2unix

dos2unix takes filename as an argument. I need to make it generic so that it can take either a file or directories and then search recursively in directories and convert all files in the tree structure from dos to Unix. I am using KornShell (ksh).
Please help

Thanks.

Comment: Use find command: `find path  -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;`

Comment: It is not working for sub directories and also if main directory has sub directories and some files in it. Eg: If i have a directory abc and it has directories temp temp1 and files t1.txt t2.txt.then this command does not cover all sub directories

Comment: it works in `bash` atleast. did you give main directory in the place of `path`

Comment: try `-maxdepth` option. Read `man 1 find`.

Comment: Thanks John. I am attaching script for your reference.Please see this is not working :(

Comment: #!/bin/ksh var=$1 for i in `cat $var` do if [ -d "$i" ]; then cd $i find . -name *.* -maxdepth -exec dos2unix {} \; else echo "Processing $i file..." dos2unix -437 $i fi done

Comment: `#!/bin/ksh
if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
   find "$1" -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
fi`

Answer (score 6):

Use `find`:

```
find file-path -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Comment: How can I exclude hidden files (starting with ., e.g. .git/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried Prince John's answer on SunOS 5.10 with a KornShell, and it didn't work.

Apparently, because the `dos2unix` command was missing the output file, so it only printed to the stdout.

This modification to his answer worked for me.

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} {} \;
```

Comment: Dos2unix is not part of the Unix standard. Their are many different implementations. People should always consult the man page first.

Comment: True.
This is the man page shown in my system:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/dos2unix-1/index.html